# How to append to PATH when starting integrated terminal in VisualStudio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I need to append an additional folder to my PATH environment variable when I run PowerShell from VisualStudio Code. This change should only exist when running PowerShell from within VisualStudio, since I don't want those extra utilities to be available otherwise (i.e. Updating the PATH variable in Windows settings is not an option.)

I made a few attempts at modifying my user settings but none seem to work.

**Attempt 1**

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : [
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command \"& {$Env:Path += ';C:\\tools'}\""
    ]
```

Result: PowerShell starts with the following error.

```
-Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -Command "& {$Env:Path += 'C:\tools'}"
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Command:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**Attempt 2**

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : [
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command", 
        "\"& {$Env:Path += 'C:\\tools'}\""
    ]
```

Result: PowerShell starts with the following output, but the "C:\tools" dir is not appended to the PATH env variable.

```
& {C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;... += 'C:\tools'}
```

Does anyone know how to invoke PowerShell with an expanded PATH variable from VisualStudio Code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with VSCode, but it seems like Attempt 1 is close based on the error. I would think the following would work:

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : [
    "-NoExit",
    "$Env:Path += ';C:\\tools'"
]
```

Comment: Your solution is almost right. It turns out that the `-Command` argument is not needed. This seems to work as expected `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : [
    "-NoExit",
    "$Env:Path += \";C:\\tools\""
]`

Comment: Edited to remove the quotes around the entire PS command that will make it function.

Comment: Hmm, "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" is deprecated and "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" is not available anymore. I really want to be able to set PATH inside VSC. Our company won't let us modify the system-wise PATH.